# deadbolt2 and implicit request

Tags: scala, playframework, deadbolt-2

I'm trying to integrate Deadbolt2 into my play framework 2.4 application.

A have following piece of code in my controller

```
import be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.{ActionBuilders, AuthenticatedRequest, DeadboltActions}
import be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.cache.HandlerCache
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.mvc.{AnyContent, _}
import modules.user.security.{Authenticator, HandlerKeys, MyDeadboltHandler}

class Login @Inject() (deadbolt: DeadboltActions, handlers: HandlerCache, actionBuilder: ActionBuilders) extends Controller {
    //...
    def login = deadbolt.SubjectNotPresent() {
      Action { implicit request =>
        Ok(login(loginForm))
      }
    }
}
```

And I got error `missing parameter type`. I'm following [deadbolt examples](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala-examples), which helps me a lot, but I can't figure out how to pass implicit request into action.

My template begins like this:

```
@(loginForm: Form[LoginForm])(implicit flash: Flash)
```

Using `Action` directly without `deadbolt.SubjectNotPresent()` works well.

Comment: What about your imports?

Comment: @manub question updated

Comment: Which version of deadbolt are you using? If it's 2.4.4 there's been a change to switch out the implicit request for an explicit authenticated request. See https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-auth0-scala for an example. I'll write up a proper answer when I'm not using a smartphone.

Comment: @SteveChaloner yes, I'm using 2.4.4. Thanks, I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: @PeterKrejci I've updated the docs at https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala - the answer is based (read: copy/pasted) from there.  If the answer isn't clear, can you let me know so I can also improve the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One persistent question that keeps coming up is "how do I get the subject in an authorized action?".  As of Deadbolt 2.5, the request passed into an action has been replaced with an `AuthenticatedRequest` which contains an `Option[Subject]`.  As users of 2.4 also want this feature, it has been included in 2.4.4 as a breaking change.

The following examples use `SubjectPresent` as an example, but the same change applies to all authorization constraints.

When using action builders, in place of

```
def index = actionBuilder.SubjectPresentAction().defaultHandler() { implicit request
  Ok(accessOk()) 
}
```

we now have

```
def index = actionBuilder.SubjectPresentAction().defaultHandler() { authRequest =>
  Future {
    Ok(accessOk()) 
  }
}
```

When using action composition, in place of

```
def index = deadbolt.SubjectPresent() { implicit request
    Action {
        Ok(accessOk())
    }
}
```

we now have

```
def someFunctionA = deadbolt.SubjectPresent()() { authRequest =>
  Future {
    Ok("Content accessible")
  }
}
```

The `getSubject()` function of the `DeadboltHandler` trait now takes an `AuthenticatedRequest` instead of a `Request`.

```
override def getSubject[A](request: AuthenticatedRequest[A]): Future[Option[Subject]] = 
  request.subject match {
    case Some(user) => Future {request.subject}
    case None => // get from database, identity platform, cache, whatever
  }
```

What this means for your app is

```
def login = deadbolt.SubjectNotPresent() {
  Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(login(loginForm))
  }
}
```

becomes

```
def login = deadbolt.SubjectNotPresent()() { authRequest =>
  Future {
    Ok(login(loginForm))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything works fine now! I'll continue using your documentation and I'll give you a feedback when my project moves on a little bit.